# Contig Extension - Search for smallest extension

Tags: python, algorithm, biopython

i want to write a function that extends contigs (overlapping dna sequences) into a large one. For that i need to find overlapping sequences from a dictionary consisting of those sequences as keys and values.
I need to find the "smallest extension" to the right and left of the initial sequence but i couldn't come up with any ideas how to actually look for the smallest one. I'm still going through the documentation but haven't found anything useful so far so if anybody could point me to a method or show me how i could get not any extension but the smallest one i would appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you extends contigs by small reads, use 10, as here:
http://sco.h-its.org/exelixis/web/software/pear/doc.html

Else if you concatenate large contigs, maybe 10% of length may be useful?
You may use threshold 10% and remove matched sequences. Next you decrease threshold to 8% of length and do matching again.

You shouldn`t decrease that below 10.